# Paraxial Spherical wave emanating from point source

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics, spherical-harmonics

I'm reading through chapter 5.3.1(Impulse response of a Positive lens), in Goodman's "Fourier Optics"(p.109). An object is placed a distance $z_1$ in front of a lens.

If we place a point source at the object plane, meaning a $\delta$ function at coordinates $(x,y)=(\xi,\eta)$ of that plane,i.e. $U_0(x,y)=\delta(x-\xi,y-\eta)$.

If we look a distance $z_1$ away from this point source and stay close to the z-axis, then according to the book, the incident wave on the lens will appear a spherical wave diverging from that point, which in the paraxial approx. has the following form:
$$
U_l(x,y)=\frac{1}{j\lambda z_1} \cdot exp(\frac{jk}{2z_1}\cdot [(x-\xi)^2+(y-\eta)^2])
$$

Could someone elaborate how this is derived?

I know that a unit-amplitude,diverging spherical wave emanating from $(\xi,\eta)$ is generally given by:
$$
\frac{exp(jk(r-r_0))}{r-r_0}
$$
Where $r_0=(\xi,\eta,0)$.
Furthermore, I know from the paraxial approximation that this leads to approximating $r=z+\frac{(x-\xi)^2+(y-\eta)^2}{2z}$, for which in the exponent we take all of the terms and for the denominator only the first term. Furthermore, we usually ignore the constant phase factor $exp(jkz)$, but this would lead to:

$$
U(x,y)=\frac{exp(\frac{jk}{2z_1}\cdot [(x-\xi)^2+(y-\eta)^2])}{z}
$$
which misses the $\frac{1}{j\lambda}$ term..

Comment: see section 4.2 The Fresnel Approximation